# Get distrubtion group email address from message tracking logs

Tags: powershell, exchange, exchange-2010

I'm trying to find all messages sent to a specific mail distribution list from all users and all other mail distribution lists from our Exchange 2010 servers.

I'm using the following powershell command

```
Get-MailBoxServer | Get-MessageTrackingLog -ResultSize unlimited -Recipients All_@test.com -EventId RECEIVE |select MessageID,timestamp,Sender,@{Name="Recipients";Expression={$_.recipients}},MessageSubject | Export-Csv -Path "C:\sendall\MailboxReceiveAll.csv" -NoTypeInformation
```

While this does work, in that I get the data, but rather than the distribution group address appearing for Sender, the actual user's email address who composed and sent the mail on behalf of the group is returned.

Is there a way to get the distribution list email address or display name to be displayed as the sender or is this working as designed?

Answer (score 0, accepted):

The `Sender` field in the message tracking log is specified with the `Sender` property in the message header(**[Table2 Fields that are Used to Classify Each Message Tracking Event](https://docs.microsoft.com/en-us/previous-versions/office/exchange-server-2010/bb124375(v=exchg.141)#information-that-is-written-to-the-message-tracking-log)**):
[image]

Besides, here is a snapshot of my .csv file:
[image]

Therefore, based on the test result and the official documentation, if we use a delegate to "**Send On Behalf Of**" a group to recipients, there will be a `Sender` property in the message header so much so that message tracking log will take the delegate email address as the **`Sender`** field, this is working as designed.

However, if a user "**Send As**" a group, the `Sender` field will still display the email address of the group.

Comment: Wang
Thanks for your reply.
I double checked the settings and actually the group has send as permissions, not send on behalf, the header of the mail in outlook shows the groups address as the sender, but the tracking logs show the user's address.
I think the issue might be that the user also has send as permission for the group

Comment: Just to clarify on the above, the user has send as permission against the group in AD, the group itself also has the send as permission granted, and the user is also a member of the group.